# Get Result of a field using Javascript & PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page which retrieves rows from database.

After retrieving the rows, I want user to enter an ordered quantity.

The system should automatically calculate the difference between the DB qty and ordered qty and place the balance in the balance field.This should be done for all the field, which will be stored in the DB after processing.

I tried the code below, which works for only the first rows, but not the rest row. See code and advice where i am missing something .

HTML Code :

```
<tr>
    <td>
       <input type="text"  name="qnty[]" value="<?php echo $r['qty'];?>" id="qty"/> 
    </td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="oqty[]"  placeholder="Qty Ordered" id="oqty" onblur="calbal();"/></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="obal[]"  placeholder="Qty Ordered" id="bal" readonly="readonly"/></td>
</tr>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calbal(){
    var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value;
    var oqty = document.getElementById("oqty").value;
    var bal = qty-oqty;
    document.getElementById("bal").value=bal;
    //document.getElementById("bal").focus();  
  }
 </script>
```

I have like 10 rows, which should be respond each to the onblur event, but only the first row does.[image]

Comment: This will pick only the first element containing the id `qty`, you need to use something else.

Comment: You can for example use `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look attached snippet.

Your code may need some change for the better output. Make each textbox unique using id.

```js
function calbal(id){
  
    var qty = document.getElementById("qty_"+id).value;
    var oqty = document.getElementById("oqty_"+id).value;
    var bal = qty-oqty;
    document.getElementById("bal_"+id).value=bal;
    //document.getElementById("bal").focus();  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td>
       <input type="text" name="qnty[]" value="11" id="qty_1"/> 
    </td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap">
      <input type="text" name="oqty[]"  placeholder="Qty Ordered" id="oqty_1" onblur="calbal(1);"/></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="obal[]"  placeholder="Qty Ordered" id="bal_1" readonly="readonly"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
       <input type="text" name="qnty[]" value="12" id="qty_2"/> 
    </td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="oqty[]"  placeholder="Qty Ordered" id="oqty_2"  onblur="calbal(2);"/></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="obal[]"  placeholder="Qty Ordered" id="bal_2" readonly="readonly"/></td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>
       <input type="text" name="qnty[]" value="13" id="qty_3"/> 
    </td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="oqty[]"  placeholder="Qty Ordered" id="oqty_3"   onblur="calbal(3);"/></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="obal[]"  placeholder="Qty Ordered" id="bal_3" readonly="readonly"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer was very useful. 100% working and perfectly fit into my code.

Comment: Thanks all, for your contribution and response.